# Anyone more problem to install Studio Code Server (VSCode) on HA 2023.1.2?

Tags: visual-studio-code, home-assistant

I am a bit new on Home Assistant and have got VSCode installed as Add-on for a while.
But some days ago I upgraded the HA core to 2023.1.2. from a 2022.11 something version.
And I updated my HA system from a Backup that did not have the VSCode so I needed to install it again.
But now I get "This add-on is not compatible with the processor or the operating system you have installed on your device".
I run the HA on a Rasberry Pi 3b and it was not problem to install and run VSCode on HA 2022.11.

Anyone have the same problem or an idea how to solve it?

I chose the Studio Code Server as Add-on in Home Assistant.
And the fault message comes directly so I can not click the Install button.

Comment: "And the fault message comes directly"   Please share the complete error message

Comment: This is the error message: "This add-on is not compatible with the processor or the operating system you have installed on your device".  Nothing more.

Comment: A little bit of research found: https://community.home-assistant.io/t/home-assistant-community-add-on-visual-studio-code/107863/12